# Flash/Actionscript preloader and button onRelease problem

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

using this as my actionscript for preloader:

```
if(_root.getBytesLoaded() != _root.getTotalBytes()) {
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

getting error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 2, Line 1   1120: Access of undefined property _root.
```

this is my buttons actionscript:

```
    stop();
home_btn.onRelease = function () {
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
page1_btn.onRelease = function (){
    gotoAndStop(4);
}
page2_btn.onRelease = function (){
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

and error :

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 3, Line 2   1119: Access of possibly undefined property onRelease through a reference with static type fl.controls:Button.
```

id like to get my website working. can you help me guys?
what im i doin wrong? id like to use the latest actionscript.

Comment: Do you use ActionScript 2 as a publishing setting? The code above is for AS2, maybe your setting are in AS3.

Comment: Yeah, this code is definitely as2. The "_" prefix was removed from most properties and listeners like "on release" are done quite differently. You probably are exporting in as3. solution: convert code to as3 ;)

Comment: @Bosworth99 anemgyenge : can you post the AS3 code as an answer? i can't seem to get to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direct translation of your code to AS3:

Frame 2:

```as
if (root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded != root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal) {
     gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Frame 3:

```as
stop();

home_btn.mouseChildren = page1.mouseChildren = page2.mouseChildren = false;
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
page1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
page2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
     switch(e.target) {
          case home_btn : gotoAndStop(3); break;
          case page1_btn : gotoAndStop(4); break;
          case page2_btn : gotoAndStop(5); break;
     }
}
```

With that said...I would recommend not loading your assets this way. I would create a "shell" SWF that loads this "main" SWF. This will give you a more accurate load. Also, if you haven't already, start looking into getting your code off of the timeline and into external classes (if you're planning on using AS3). AS3 is an object-oriented programming language and is intended to be used this way. What you have now will work, but learning this method will save you a lot of headaches. Here is a good starting point: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html.

Comment: I strongly suggest taking @Corey into serious consideration. Avoid timeline code at all cost. Learn the basics of OOP and get busy with as3. You will be very glad you did.

Comment: I'll do you one better. I laid out a pretty complete "simple" preloader on another thread [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396997/problems-preloading-with-export-on-frame-2/5408262#5408262). It even includes html and js to plant this preloader swf on the page. enjoy.